# Change values of a python dictionary contigent on the other values of the dictionary

Tags: python, default-value

Is there a possibility to make the default input-values dependent on one of the input-values? I tried this:

```
def getHigh(pricedata, start=min(pricedata), end=max(pricedata)):
    ## do something
```

But it doesn't work, because pricedata is not yet defined.

Comment: I recommend never to do any super advanced stuff like that inside the function arguments, but rather in the function body, where you can define it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. They were really a great help. Probably best for me to stick to the plain&simple answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep it simple :)

```
def getHigh(pricedata, start=None, end=None):
    start = min(pricedata) if start is None else start
    end = max(pricedata) if end is None else end
```

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, you can do this using `None` and testing for it.

```
def getHigh(pricedata, start=None, end=None):
    start = min(pricedata) if start is None else start
    end   = max(pricedata) if end is None else end
```

In the particular case where you're setting a range and will be processing only items in that range, you can use defaults that include all possible values:

```
def getHigh(pricedata, start=float("-inf"), end=float("+inf")):
    # consider only items between start and end, inclusive
    pricedata = [datum for datum in pricedata if start <= datum <= end]
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do what you asked are:

```
def getHigh(pricedata, start=None, end=None):
    if start is None:
        start = min(pricedata)
    if end is None:
        end = max(pricedata)
```

and...

```
def getHigh(pricedata, **kwargs):
    start = kwargs.get("start", min(pricedata))
    end = kwargs.get("end",max(pricedata))
```

Comment: Problem with second solution is that the function will accept any named arguments and won't complain if they're not used. One could use .pop() instead of .get() and check if dict ends up empty.

Comment: Well, that's true that it will accept any named arguments, but I'm not sure why that would cause a problem, in general (I mean, the only case I can think of would be if you were passing `**kwargs` on to another function, and you were trying to shield that call).  It doesn't pollute your namespace, and ignoring them is safe.  I'd be curious to know what specific problem you feel that this causes.

Comment: One problem with using keyword arguments is that `help()` and other automated documentation tools won't tell you what arguments the function accepts. This may or may not be a big deal. Also, it requires that the optional parameters be passed as keyword arguments, when there is probably no need for that.